# Fluent Validation not finding properties on a ResourceManager class used for localization

Tags: c#, localization, nancy, fluentvalidation

I am using Fluent Validation inside a NancyFX application.
Installed using the nuget package: `Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation`

I wrote my own property Validator class and have done a localization of the error message which can be obtained via the `Strings.invalid_ip` property.

All other localizations work fine within my project, the exception is Fluent Validation which can't find any properties on the `Strings` resource manager class.

```
namespace LmsNg.Validators
{
    public class IsIpAddressValidator : PropertyValidator
    {
        public IsIpAddressValidator()
            : base(() => Strings.invalid_ip)

            //also tried another overload, but the same exception happens
            //base("invalid_ip", typeof(Strings))
        {
        }

        protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
            var ip = context.PropertyValue as string;
            IPAddress address;

            if (ip != null && IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out address))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: file properties]

Once `IsIpAddressValidator` gets used and when validation returns false I get an exception.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in FluentValidation.dll but was not handled in user code

`System.InvalidOperationExcepction: Could not find a property named 'invalid_ip' on type 'LmsNg.Resources.Strings'.`

Stacktrace:

```
   at FluentValidation.Resources.StaticResourceAccessorBuilder.GetResourceAccessor(Type resourceType, String resourceName) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Resources\IResourceAccessorBuilder.cs:line 29
   at FluentValidation.Resources.LocalizedStringSource..ctor(Type resourceType, String resourceName, IResourceAccessorBuilder resourceAccessorBuilder) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Resources\LocalizedStringSource.cs:line 42
   at FluentValidation.Resources.LocalizedStringSource.CreateFromExpression(Expression`1 expression, IResourceAccessorBuilder resourceProviderSelectionStrategy) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Resources\LocalizedStringSource.cs:line 66
   at FluentValidation.Validators.PropertyValidator..ctor(Expression`1 errorMessageResourceSelector) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Validators\PropertyValidator.cs:line 54
   at LmsNg.Validators.IsIpAddressValidator..ctor() in d:\WorkSpace\VisualStudio\LmsNg\LmsNg\Validators\IsIpAddressValidator.cs:line 16
   at LmsNg.Modules.Networks.NetworkValidator..ctor() in d:\WorkSpace\VisualStudio\LmsNg\LmsNg\Modules\Networks\NetworkValidator.cs:line 16
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
```

Is the `Build Action` of my `.resx` files incorrect? I tried a couple of combiniations but the same error still happens.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, by default the `.resx` files generate `.cs` files that contain the `internal` modifier on classes/fields.

Which means these are not accessible from a different assembly, in this case `FluentValidation.dll`.

Changing the `Custom Tool` of each `.resx` file in the properties pane

from: `ResXFileCodeGenerator`
to: `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`

helped with the problem since now the code that gets generated contains a `public` modifier instead of `internal`.

Comment: Actually this is not entirely correct. Fluent validation accesses the resources auto-generated class via reflection. But it gets each property and its getter method expecting them to be public. You can see that in https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/88255e1fbd1970770b8d3ee5469cabeadb180fa1/src/FluentValidation/Resources/IResourceAccessorBuilder.cs#L26. So when they're auto-generated as internal it will fail to obtain them.